# three.js: Bright edges in shadows

Tags: three.js

It seems that when an object casts and receives shadows you get this bright edge that looks like light bleeding through. Is there any way to overcome this? In the snippet I give here you can see that the shadow from the cylinder on the two cubes doesn't have the issue in the picture, but on the back is where you see the line happening.

[image]

```js
width = window.innerWidth
height = window.innerHeight

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
renderer.setClearColor(0xeeeeee)
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(width, height)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

scene = new THREE.Scene()
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, width / height, 0.1, 3000)
camera.position.set(-45, 47, 75)
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.minDistance = 40
controls.maxDistance = 1300
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF0000, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 75})

scene.add(camera, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.4))
light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8)

renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap
light.castShadow = true
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 3072
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 3072
light.shadow.camera.left = 500

function shadow(w) {
  w.castShadow = true
  w.receiveShadow = true
}

camera.add(light)
light.position.y += 60
light.position.x += 70

requestAnimationFrame(function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
})

b = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20), material)
shadow(b)
scene.add(b)

c = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5,5,10,32), material)
c.position.set(3,15,3)
shadow(c)
scene.add(c)

d = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 10, 1), material)
d.position.set(3,15,-5)
shadow(d)
scene.add(d)
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can play around with the [shadow map bias](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/lights/shadows/LightShadow.bias) e.g. `light.shadow.bias = 0.00005`

Comment: I did try that but the lines were still there and that also caused shadows in unwanted places.